# Refactor code for API wrapper

Tags: c#, api

I am looking for ways to improve my API wrapper for Pocket. So far, my code is quite compact and nice (I think), but I feel like there must be a better way to do this.

This is the part where I think a lot of code redundancy due to different parameters that need to be serialized to Json and later send to server.

```
        public async Task<List<ItemRetrieved>> GetAllUnreadAsync(int sinceInUnixTime = 0)
        {
            var requestUrl = MakeRequestUri("v3/get");

            var request = new HttpRequest(HttpMethod.Post, requestUrl);

            request.AddBody(new
                {
                    consumer_key = _consumerKey,
                    access_token = _accessToken,
                    state = "unread",
                    sort = "newest",
                    since = sinceInUnixTime
                });

            var response = await SendAsync<ItemRetrievedWrapper>(request);

            return response.List.Values.ToList();
        }

    public async Task<List<ItemRetrieved>> GetFavoriteAsync(int sinceInUnixTime = 0)
    {
        var requestUrl = MakeRequestUri("v3/get");

        var request = new HttpRequest(HttpMethod.Post, requestUrl);

        request.AddBody(new
            {
                consumer_key = _consumerKey,
                access_token = _accessToken,
                favorite = 1,
                sort = "newest",
                since = sinceInUnixTime
            });

        var response = await SendAsync<ItemRetrievedWrapper>(request);

        return response.List.Values.ToList();
    }
```

I have few other methods that look like this as well but the only different is the anonymous object passed inside the `AddBody`. The anonymous object is the parameters that need to be set. `AddBody` will serialize the object into Json.

My idea currently is to create a separate class/object for the parameters and use method chaining to build up the parameters before passing it into `AddBody`.

Maybe looks something like this.

```
var requestParams = new RequestParams();
requestParams.SortBy("newest").Since(2312321312).IsFavorite(true);
request.AddBody(requestParams);
```

Are there any other good ways I can refactor my code?

If you need to see the big picture, you can take a look here at my Github https://github.com/shulhi/PocketNet

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you should refactor your code so that you don't repeat yourself:

```
private async Task<List<ItemRetrieved>> GetValuesAsync(object parametersAsAnonymousObject)
{
    var requestUrl = MakeRequestUri("v3/get");

    var request = new HttpRequest(HttpMethod.Post, requestUrl);
    request.AddBody(parametersAsAnonymousObject);

    var response = await SendAsync<ItemRetrievedWrapper>(request);
    return response.List.Values.ToList();
}

public Task<List<ItemRetrieved>> GetAllUnreadAsync(int sinceInUnixTime = 0)
{
    return GetValuesAsync(new
        {
            consumer_key = _consumerKey,
            access_token = _accessToken,
            state = "unread",
            sort = "newest",
            since = sinceInUnixTime
        });
}

public Task<List<ItemRetrieved>> GetFavoriteAsync(int sinceInUnixTime = 0)
{
    return GetValuesAsync(new
        {
            consumer_key = _consumerKey,
            access_token = _accessToken,
            favorite = 1,
            sort = "newest",
            since = sinceInUnixTime
        });
}
```

This sill repeats `consumer_key` and `access_token`, but I think getting rid of that repetition would be too complicated, so it's not worth it (unless you have big number of these methods).